# Focusing and nonfocusing nonlinear terms

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, hyperbolic-pde

What is the *mathematical* and *physical* meaning of the terms *focusing* and *nonfocusing* when they refer to nonlinear terms in a dispersive equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology focusing versus defocusing comes from electromagnetic wave propagation in a material with a refractive index $n=\alpha|E|^2$ that depends on the energy density of the electric field (proportional to the field strength squared). The corresponding wave equation for propagation along the $z$-axis is the nonlinear Schrödinger equation,
$$ i\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial x^2}+ \alpha|E|^2 E = 0.$$

The width in the transverse $x$-direction of the beam increases with increasing $z$ for $\alpha<0$ (*defocusing*), while it decreases for $\alpha>0$ (*focusing*). Defocusing is the normal behavior, the focusing behavior occurs under special circumstances, see the [Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-focusing)

Comment: Thank you. That's very interesting. Do you have a  reference for this topic (from the mathematical point of view)?

Comment: [Weinstein's review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05449) seems a useful introduction.

Comment: Thank you very much.